# Consume RSS Feed from Bloomberg news

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

i have been searching for solution to consume bloomberg rss feed.

please have a look at their XML [Bloomberg rss feed](http://www.bloomberg.com/feed/podcast/on-the-economy.xml)

as you can see, there is `<itunes:summary>` which i wanna to get, but don't know how.

at the moment, i am using this

```
List<FeedModel> list = new List<FeedModel>();
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(rssUri);

SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

var feedItems = from item in feed.Items
                select new FeedModel()
                {
                    Content = item.Summary.Text,
                    Id = item.Id,
                    PublishDate = item.PublishDate.DateTime.ToString(),
                    Title = item.Title.Text,
                    Link = item.Links.First().Uri.ToString()
                };
return feedItems.ToList();
```

i consume [yahoo news](http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/world) it works fine but not the bloomberg. please help?

**Extra info**

i am a php developer, i need to develop a small module for my company in c#.

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework are you using / targeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather simple:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://www.bloomberg.com/feed/podcast/on-the-economy.xml");

XNamespace itunes = "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd";


var query = doc.Root.Elements("channel")
                .Elements("item")
                .Select(p => new BloomergFeeds
                {
                    Title = p.Element("title").Value,
                    Link = p.Element("link").Value,
                    Guid = p.Element("guid").Value,
                    PublishDate = p.Element("pubDate").Value,
                    Itunes = new Itunes
                    {
                        Author = p.Elements(itunes + "author").First().Value,
                        Subtitle = p.Elements(itunes + "subtitle").First().Value,
                        Summary = p.Elements(itunes + "summary").First().Value,
                        Duration = p.Elements(itunes + "duration").First().Value,
                        Keywords = p.Elements(itunes + "keywords").First().Value,
                    }
                }).ToList();


 public class BloomergFeeds
 {
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Link { get; set; }
     public string Guid { get; set; }
     public string PublishDate { get; set; }
     public Itunes Itunes { get; set; }
  }

  public class Itunes
  {
     public string Author { get; set; }
     public string Subtitle { get; set; }
     public string Summary { get; set; }
     public string Duration { get; set; }
     public string Keywords { get; set; }
  }
```

Output is nicely formatted:

[image]

Obviously you can go even further and split the keywords to a new property of `List<string>`, add a new property (enclosure) for link etc. Whatever you want.

Enjoy.

Comment: Plurpy, thanks this is great solution, as i still new in c#, how i want to display Itunes in let say GridView? i tried dataSource = query but it does't show Itunes part :)

Comment: Please mark my solution as an answer. Are you doing WPF or WinForms app?

Comment: erm. i am doing web page, which is .aspx. btw. both answers actually work, i don know which to choose ><

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example of how to get the extended properties.

**Usage**

```
var model = GenerateModelFromRssFeed("http://www.bloomberg.com/feed/podcast/on-the-economy.xml");
```

**Code**

```
public class FeedModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<FeedModel> GenerateModelFromRssFeed(string feedUri)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(feedUri)) throw new ArgumentNullException(feedUri);

    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(feedUri))
    {

        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        if (feed == null) throw new ApplicationException("Bloomberg feed cannot be downloaded");

        return from item in feed.Items
                select new FeedModel
                {
                    // this looks a little ugly but is necessary to check if the object (Summary) is null as an 
                    // exception will be thrown when trying to access a property on a null object
                    Content = item.Summary == null ? string.Empty : item.Summary.Text,
                    Id = item.Id,
                    PublishDate = item.Summary == null ? DateTime.MaxValue : item.PublishDate.DateTime,
                    Title = item.Title == null ? string.Empty : item.Title.Text,
                    Link = item.Links.Any() ? item.Links.First().Uri.ToString() : string.Empty,

                    // add in additional logic to test if the element extension is not null
                    Summary = item.ElementExtensions.FirstOrDefault(x => x != null && x.GetObject<XElement>().Name.LocalName.ToLowerInvariant() == "summary").GetObject<XElement>().Value
                };
    }
}
```

You can obviously make the `GenerateModelFromRssFeed` method as static depending on your needs.

Comment: Kane, thanks for this. do you mind explain how you use the ElementExtensions to obtain the data? this solution works, but now i need to get yahoo weather rss which is in <yweather:condition>